# Get latest element with certain prefix in JMESPath

Tags: jmespath

I have a JSON input like that:

```json
{
  "details": [
    {
      "file": [
        "xxx-abc"
      ],
      "filePushedAt": "2021-10-25T09:31:39+02:00"
    },
    {
      "file": [
        "xxx-dfg"
      ],
      "filePushedAt": "2021-11-08T16:24:05+01:00"
    },
    {
      "file": [
        "hij"
      ],
      "filePushedAt": "2022-01-26T15:24:17+01:00"
    },
    {
      "file": [
        "xxx-klm"
      ],
      "filePushedAt": "2022-01-27T15:24:18+01:00"
    },
    {
      "file": [
        "opr"
      ],
      "filePushedAt": "2021-11-28T09:31:39+02:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using `JMESPath` I need to get the latest file (latest `filePushedAt`) which consists `xxx` prefix in file array.

I am able to extract files names in order by using

```
sort_by(details,& filePushedAt)[*].file[*]
```

but cannot complete the task. I'm wondering if it is even possible without `jq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to filter the `file` arrays nested in the `details` one, you need to filter at the `details` level.
You will need the [`starts_with` function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with) in order to filter all elements of the `file` arrays for the prefix `xxx`.

So, knowing all this, we have the query:

```
details[?file[?starts_with(@,`xxx`)]]
```

That gives us the filtered array:

```json
[
  {
    "file": [
      "xxx-abc"
    ],
    "filePushedAt": "2021-10-25T09:31:39+02:00"
  },
  {
    "file": [
      "xxx-dfg"
    ],
    "filePushedAt": "2021-11-08T16:24:05+01:00"
  },
  {
    "file": [
      "xxx-klm"
    ],
    "filePushedAt": "2022-01-27T15:24:18+01:00"
  }
]
```

Now, to fulfil you requirement, you still need, a [`sort_by`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#func-sort-by), a [`reverse`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#reverse), because `sort_by` does not have an option to sort ascending or descending, and to select the first item of the array, with `[0]`.

So, now, given the query

```
reverse(sort_by(details[?file[?starts_with(@,`xxx`)]], &filePushedAt))[0]
```

You do have the object you were looking for:

```json
{
  "file": [
    "xxx-klm"
  ],
  "filePushedAt": "2022-01-27T15:24:18+01:00"
}
```

Comment: That's great answer. Thank you. Is it easy to reverse this logic meaning find the one which does not start with `xxx`?

Comment: Sure, the not is an exclamation mark, so: ```reverse(sort_by(details[?file[?!starts_with(@,`xxx`)]], & filePushedAt))[0]```